# Intellij: how to keep existing end-of-line mixed styles when saving?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, diff, line-breaks

Intellij: how to keep existing end-of-line styles when saving?

We have a file with mixed EOL styles (from hex viewer, how happened?)

```
   0A     \n
   0D 0A  \r\n
```

When saving the existing file with one-line change, many lines are changed on disk (from svn diff).

```
svn diff
```

Noted that some lines are added (no deletions). svn diff has a bug.
svn stores file diff(s) in repository. If svn diff has a bug, will the repository be actually corrupted?

```
svn diff -x "-w --ignore-eol-style"
```

gave me correct result.

My question is that: how to keep existing EOL styles (mixed in the file) when saving and prevent generating invisible diffs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related issue on YouTrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171699/Keep-differents-lines-separators-in-the-file

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.